# Get distance for two points

Tags: c++

I need some help getting the distance value between two points,

First, I set up the struct for Point and defined two points,

```
typedef struct {
  double x;
  double y;
} Point;

Point p1;
p1.x = 0;
p1.y = 0;
Point p2;
p2.x = 1;
p2.y = 0;
```

And the getLength function is like,

```
double getLength(Point a, Point b) {
  double sum = sqrt(pow((b.x - a.x), 2) + pow((a.y - b.y), 2));
  return sum;
}
```

I ran the code as,

```
double res = getLength(p1, p2);
printf("length is %d \n", res);
```

Each time, I get the different large numbers for 'res,' for example,

```
length is 16339616
length is 19378848
length is 9654944
```

Instead of 1 for this case (the distance between p1 and p2 is 1), could you please tell me what is the reason for this and how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: `%d` is the format specifier for an `int`. Use `%f` with `printf` for a `double` argument.

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are two *very* different languages. Don't tag multiple different languages, only the language you're actually using. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Works well with the correct format specifier. However, it's suspicious that you get different results each time. A [mre] would be useful to know wether or not this is the only error.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, and sorry for any mistakes I did, I will be careful next time.

Comment: @ShadyNemo You can always [edit] and improve your question.

Comment: `typedef struct` no don't do this, especially in C++ you never need that

Answer (score 1):

Specifier `%d` is used in function `printf()` for printing integers. When you print float values, you need to use `%f` instead.

Details: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

So, the following code

```
Point p1;
p1.x = 0;
p1.y = 1;
Point p2;
p2.x = 1;
p2.y = 0;

double res = getLength(p1, p2);
printf("length is %f \n", res);
```

will print this:

```
length is 1.414214
```